# Access object from DI (scoped) in EF.Core value converter

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I wrote a [value converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations) that converts objects to JSON strings. A new requirement is that values inside the JSON should be localizable. Therefor I want to write every property in the default language and the configured additional languages. The localized data is available in DI. Example:

```json
   {
      "title": "apple",
      "title_fr": "pomme",
      "title_de": "Apfel"
   }
```

When reading from the database, I need to access an object from DI that contains the desired language and uses it to deserialize the property from that language. I assume this might be possible with a `IMaterializationInterceptor`.

Comment: You can't do that. `ValueConverter` is defined during configuring `DbContext` - once per generating `Model`. And actually (usually) once per application run. If you need advise improve your question with more details.

Comment: `IMaterializationInterceptor` passes `DbContext` - Cast this context to your class and get correct translation.

Comment: That will work for reading data, but how can I do the writing?

Comment: Intercept `SaveChanges`?

Comment: That won't do because in `SaveChanges` I got an object with only the `title` property, `title_fr` and `title_de` must be added by the ValueConverter.